# How do you import an accdb database from Access into SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

The old techniques don't seem to work.  I tried using various drives, but the Access driver options in SQL Server Import Export Utility (64-bit), on the Data Source page, only want .mdb files (there is no option for .accdb).  When selecting "all files", and selecting the .accdb file, the wizard throws an error stating that the wrong version of Excel is installed (even though this has been tried with both Office 365 and Office 2016).

Comment: The easiest way may be to save your **.accdb** as a **.mdb** and import that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select one of the Microsoft Access providers and when you browse for a file choose `All Files (*.*)` in the file type drop-down instead of `Microsoft Access Files (*.mdb)`.  From there you should be able to select your .accdb file and continue with the import.

For me this works for both Access providers listed below (and I have not installed any other additional providers):

- Microsoft Access (Microsoft Access Database Engine)
- Microsoft Access (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0)